# git: submodule tracking current branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

According to the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule---branch), I should be able to run this command:

```
git submodule add -b . https://my/repo
```

And have a sub-module added, which will track head of the current branch of the super project.

> Branch of repository to add as submodule. The name of the branch is recorded as submodule..branch in .gitmodules for update --remote. A special value of . is used to indicate that the name of the branch in the submodule should be the same name as the current branch in the current repository.

But when I do this, I get this error:

> fatal: 'origin/.' is not a commit and a branch '.' cannot be created from it

I'm running git 2.21.  Have I read the instructions completely wrong?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54962711/1256452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git submodule add` doesn't seem to have any code that does any sort of checking for a dot.  After the clone, it'll try and checkout the branch ".", which naturally doesn't exist.

But, `git submodule update --remote` *does* have a check, and uses "." specially.

To get this to work, you need to do:

1. `git submodule add -b master https://my/repo`
2. `git submodule set-branch --branch . REMOTE_NAME`
3. `git submodule update --remote`
4. Profit

Every time you run an update on the super project it'll get the tip of the branch.

Whether the documentation is just not clear, or a bug exists in adding a submodule, I'm not sure.

Edit: updated with Akom's comment as it's easier than editing the .gitmodules file to add the dot in as the branch name manually.

Comment: item 2 can be changed to `git submodule set-branch --branch . REMOTE_NAME` (at least that works in git 2.25.1)

Comment: Can you please give an example of the "REMOTE_NAME" should point to?

Comment: @user320550 "origin" would be typical

Comment: Maybe it is a bug since the docs don't say it doesn't work with `add`? It ofc works as expected if added to the config! I'd think using `.` with `add` that it would try to clone/checkout the sm's branch matching the super's active branch with `submodule.name.branch = .` in the config. Instead, it clones the sm (using the sm's def branch if remote or active if local) then throws a fatal error, while still leaving the submodule directory but also not only performing but staging a `git rm -rf *` inside that submodule..! Not an easy thing to search about either with the main keyword being `.`!

Answer (score 0):

Options `-b` requires a name of a branch in the repository `https://my/repo`. For example, `master`:

```
git submodule add -b master https://my/repo
```

Git cannot "track head of the current branch of the super project". The branch must be given explicitly.

When you switch branch of the superproject with `git checkout` git doesn't automatically switch branches of submodules — you have to run `git submodule update` manually or from `post-checkout` hook.

See [Why is git submodule update not automatic on git checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899792/why-is-git-submodule-update-not-automatic-on-git-checkout)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+switch+branch